# Is there any way to use Spring cloud config server hosted outside PCF environment from an application hosted with in PCF?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I have a Spring boot application hosted on the PCF environment which I wanted to connect to a Config server hosted outside the PCF. How I would be able to achieve that?
Searching online, I have found that to use PCF CUPS but I am not sure how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect to config server outside PCF (ex: consul by Hashicorp).. Using bootstrap.properties is an ideal way to fetch the config and you need to have parameters like:

```
spring.cloud.consul.host=
spring.cloud.consul.port=
spring.cloud.consul.config.name=
```

along with the related token to connect securely

```
spring.cloud.consul.config.acl-token=
```